# how install robot-pose-ekf kinetic

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

how to install the Robot-pose-ekf package in kinetic.

An error occurs with the apt-get install command:

```
After this operation, 2.653 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-bfl amd64 0.7.0-2xenial-20180809-134309-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-robot-pose-ekf amd64 1.14.4-0xenial-20190320-162431-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-bfl/ros-kinetic-bfl_0.7.0-2xenial-20180809-134309-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-robot-pose-ekf/ros-kinetic-robot-pose-ekf_1.14.4-0xenial-20190320-162431-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've already run the apt-get update command...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327067/how-install-robot-pose-ekf-kinetic/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is very likely you're running into the effects of #q325039.

Please follow the instructions there and try again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-26**:
PS: this is not about `robot-pose-ekf`, but a problem with keys not matching, leading to `apt` not being able to update the indices, leading to `apt` trying to download old versions of packages that are not there any more.